# opossum isn't retrying when I call fire

Tags: javascript, typescript, circuit-breaker

I have this code

```
  async connection(c: DependencyContainer): Promise<Connection|undefined> {
      const breaker = new CircuitBreaker((uri: string) => {
        return connect(uri)
      });
      breaker.on('failure', (err) => {
        c.resolve<Logger>(InjectToken.Logger).warn('amqp ', err);
      });
      return await breaker.fire(c.resolve<string>(InjectToken.AmqpUri));
  }
```

I see that it is called once, and `failure` is called, while running it success isn't possible as the server I'm pointed at (localhost) is not online. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer to my question, but my solution has been to switch to [cockatiel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cockatiel) it seems quite new, but it works very well and the api is very easy to work with.